# Why after that I installed node 10.1.0 it says that the installed version is the 5.6.0?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I downloaded the NPM Windows installer from here: https://nodejs.org/it/

I downloaded the **10.1.0** version and I installed it.

Why when I go into my console performing `node -v` statement I am obtaining this output?

```
C:\Users\nobil>npm -v
openssl config failed: error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process
openssl config failed: error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process
5.6.0
```

It says that the installed version is the **5.6.0** instead the expected one (**10.1.0**).

What am I missing?

And what are these openssl error messages?

Comment: thats the npm version try `node --version` or `node -v`

Answer (score 3):

You are requesting the version number of npm, whicht is part of node.
To get the node version, try:

> node -v

Answer (score 2):

That is because to see node version you've to do `node -v`.

`npm -v` shows you the npm version. npm is the package manager for node.

Answer (score 1):

> I downloaded the NPM Windows installer from here: https://nodejs.org/it/

That's the Node.js installer.

`npm` is a piece of software that is distributed with Node.js, but it isn't Node.js and has its own version number.

See `node --version` for the Node.js version number.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `node -v` or `node --version` to visualise the node version installed in your system. `npm` or the node package manager is a big repository for packages or re-usable code that you can use in your node.js application. As such, `npm` has its own version.